Azure Function Blob Trigger Not Firing for New Blobs
Azure Function with a blob trigger designed to execute whenever a new blob is uploaded to a specific container in my Azure storage account. However, the function isn't triggering as expected. I've verified that blobs are indeed being uploaded to the container, but the function remains inactive.
Function gets executing and processing all the pending files once when I visit the function app in portal.azure.com
I've double-checked the following:
The function app is running and healthy.
The storage account connection string is valid and has appropriate permissions for the function.
The blob trigger configuration in function.json (or equivalent) matches the intended container and path (if applicable).
Note: I am using consumption plan

Provide the code you have tried and also provide the folder structure  in container where blob is getting added

Do you have a lot of blobs in that Storage account? If you use the standard polling mechanism, it can miss files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#polling-and-latency

@junna not too many files hourly one blob

@rithwikbojja folder structure is simple [ Blob containers]-->Colardao2

Need code otherwise one cannot help

Function App-->Function1
It is used to fire as soon as blob reaches container, now function Gettig fire upon vising portal (Function App-->Function1)
There are no recent changes or deployments.

Below is the code which worked for me:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp161
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("rithwik/fold1/{name}", Connection = "rithcon")] Stream stream, string name)
        {
            using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
        }
    }
}

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithcon": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik54;AccountKey=hCvncfYA8EdmQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}

Then deployed to azure function and then after  deploying added connection string as below:

Output:
After blob gets uploaded:

The function  got triggered:


now function Gettig fire upon vising portal (Function App-->Function1) There are no recent changes or deployments.

If you are opening function and it is getting triggered this is not an expected behavior as function should only trigger whenever new blob uploads , I would suggest you to raise a support request and I would suggest you to create a new azure function app and follow my steps as i have got desired and expected result.

My function also firing with Premium plan but not with consumption plan

But I see you have mentioned that you are using Consumption Plan for Azure Function?
